# How to pass parameterized JSON value to the XSLT 2.0?

Tags: json, xslt-2.0

I have a JSON file for loading UI. Part of the file is as follows

```
{
    "tab": "Add white space",
    "name": "whitespace_Mode",
    "label": "White space mode",
    "type": "list",
    "Value": "strict",
    "values": [
        "strict",
        "preserve"
    ]
}
```

I have an issue to pass this value to XSLT. I need to write some transformations according UI value using XSLT. Could someone help me to find a way for this?

Comment: Show your input XML, your current XSLT, the code/command that you use to invoke the XSLT and the desired result XML.

Comment: Please show your work before asking and we can help with the issues you encounter if any

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 2.0 does not have any support for handling JSON, so the best solution is going to depend on what other technology is available to you.

The ideal solution would be to move to XSLT 3.0 (e.g. Saxon) which has functions like json-doc(), parse-json(), and json-to-xml() which can convert this input to something that XSLT can process.

It also depends on what you want to do with the data, which you haven't made clear.